# Cube mapping: where to create samplerCube that is sent to fragment shader?

Tags: opengl

I'm creating a cube map/skybox in OpenGL.

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 150

out vec4 vFragColor;
uniform samplerCube uCubeMap;
in vec3 texCoords;

void main() {

vFragColor = texture( uCubeMap, texCoords );

}
```

And this is in my main cpp file:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint textureId;
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

And this is called for each of the six sides:

```
glTexImage2D(face, 0, (!srgb) || g_Gl2Compatible ? GL_RGB : GL_SRGB, width, height,
             0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixData[0]);
```

where face is GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, etc. and pixData is the image file contents.

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception caught: Uniform variable uCubeMap: used in the shader codes, but not supplied. Type = GL_SAMPLER_CUBE, Size = 1
```

Where do I define uCubeMap? Is it implicitly defined by OpenGL (and if so, where), or do I have to do this myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody asked you to "define" the variable; you already did that in the shader. What they're asking you to do is tell OpenGL what texture image unit the texture comes from. Assuming you bound the texture to `GL_TEXTURE0` when you tried to render it, you then must [assign that uniform value to the texture image unit 0](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers).

This works by setting `uCubeMap`'s uniform value in the program object. Samplers are opaque uniforms, so they're set by `glProgramUniform1i` (or `glUniform1i`). You would set this uniform to 0, since you bound the texture to texture unit 0.

Comment: Thanks! When I set it equal to 0 though, it gives me this error: 
`Supplied value: type = GL_INT, size = 1
Declared in shader: type = GL_SAMPLER_CUBE, size = 1
Program ended with exit code: 255`
Do you know what is going wrong?